# In C, when is conditional "test ? : alt" form (empty true case) supported?

Tags: c, gcc, conditional-statements

In gcc, I can write `foo ? : bar` which is a shorthand form of `foo ? foo : bar` but I see that K&R doesn't mention it.

Is this something I should rely on, defined in some standard? Or just an (evil) gcc extension I should avoid?

Comment: It is an evil gcc extension that you should avoid.

Comment: I don't know why everyone hates this extension.  It is very concise and often better represents what I mean.  I wish that it would be added to the standard.  However as it is not you shouldn't use it if you desire compatibility with compilers other then gcc and clang.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a ***GCC extension*** by the name:
**[Conditionals with Omitted Operands](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals)**.

It is **not** standard c.Using `-pedantic` flag for compilation will tell you so.

> The middle operand in a conditional expression may be omitted. Then if the first operand is nonzero, its value is the value of the conditional expression.
>
> Therefore, the expression
>
> `x ? : y`
>
> has the value of x if that is nonzero; otherwise, the value of y.
>
> This example is perfectly equivalent to
>
> `x ? x : y`
>
> In this simple case, the ability to omit the middle operand is not especially useful. When it becomes useful is when the first operand does, or may (if it is a macro argument), contain a side effect. Then repeating the operand in the middle would perform the side effect twice. Omitting the middle operand uses the value already computed without the undesirable effects of recomputing it.

> **Is this something I should rely on, defined in some standard? Or just an (evil) gcc extension I should avoid?**

Depends on your requirements, If your code does'nt need to run on any other compiler implementation other than GCC then you can use it. However, if your code is to build on across different other compiler implementations then you should not use it.

Anyhow, One should aim to write as much intuitive and readable code as possible given that I would always suggest avoiding such (*ugly*)constructs.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll stop using it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a GCC extension. It's not part of the C standard, but the GCC compiler lets you use it. See its [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) for details, and be mindful of its behavioural differences to the "equivalent" ternary expression.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension included in GCC.

It *will not* work if compiling with another compiler (that does not support that extension).

So I would recommend to avoid using this type of shortcut.

EDIT: As @KevinCox pointed out, even a `DEFINE` would not work (see 2nd comment below).

Comment: It _will_ not work, I have never heard of any other compiler implementing such a (useless) feature.

Comment: This feature **can not** be properly implemented via a macro.  `#define OR(a,b) ((a)?(a):(b))` is incorrect because it may evaluate `a` twice.  This also can't be implemented via an (inline) function because it would have to be generic.